# How to create template of sharepoint subsite which is already created from template?

Tags: site-template

How to create template of SharePoint sub-site which is already created from template?

I am not able to find Solution in Solution Gallary.

Comment: I am not able to see that option even though I am administrator.

Comment: No it is not enable.

Comment: Tried , but still the same. Can't see the option.

Comment: Hi Amal , I am trying to migrate that template to 2013 from 2010. Its giving me web.config error ? Is it like I can't migrate ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should enable Publishing Feature for Saving Site as Template.

1. Enable Site Feature - SharePoint Server Publishing
2. Enable Site Collection Feature - SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure

Now you can open following URL

```
http://siteurl/_layouts/savetmpl.aspx
```